# if (x==0||7||14||21||-7||-14) {y=THURSDAY;}

Tags: c, if-statement

Can you use a bunch of or's in a row like that?

```
 if (x==0||7||14||21||-7||-14){y=THURSDAY;}
```

it doesn't seem to be working for me.
what's wrong?  Can || not be used for two else if conditions with the same then predicate?

Comment: `it doesn't seem to be working for me` **what** does not work for you?

Comment: operator `||` simply doesn't work this way.. however you should just switch to `(x % 7 == 0)`, assuming that values larger than 27 or less than -20 cannot occur

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in c anything other than 0 is considered boolean true. so your if can be read like:
if x==0 or true or true or true...
what you probably meant was `if (x==0 || x==7 || x==14 ...)`

Comment: thank you, you succinctly told me how to fix my syntax.  You gwrok Oren!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a bunch of ifs, but as there is a repeating pattern, something like modulus my be more appropriate. I.e.

```
if( x>= -14 && x<= 21 && (x %7) == 0)
```

Comment: I recommend adding parenthesis to improve readability. And of course it has to be `x % 7`

Comment: This is also a good way to do it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers are right.. but what's important is why... when using a boolean expression, you cannot let the compiler assume that if(x == 0 || .... < refers to the same variable), hence you should always specify for which variable you are evaluating on.

```
if(x == 0 || x == 7 || ...) { ... }
```

Also, it is true that the majority of prog. languages have their shorthands such as in c, anything that is not 0 is true but the same does not apply to java; be very careful differentiating the basics with the shorthands.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
x == 0||7||14||21||-7||-14
```

is **not** shorthand for

```
x == 0 || x == 7 || x == 14 || ...
```

Instead, it compares `x` to the *result* of the expression `0 || 7 || 14 || ...`, which will be 1.

Remember that the `||` operator evaluates its left operand first; if it's 0-valued, it then evaluates the right operand.  If both operands are 0-valued, the expression evaluates to 0 (false).  If the left-hand operand is non-zero, the expression evaluates to 1 (true), and the right-hand operand isn't evaluated at all.

Basically, your code is evaluated as

```
x == 0 || (7 || (14 || (21 || (-7 || -14))))
```

The left operand is 0, so we evaluate the right operand (the subexpression `(7 || (14 || (21 ||...)`.  Since `7` is non-zero, the expression evaluates to 1 (the remaining operands are not evaluated).

If you want to test `x` against multiple values, you will need to write multiple equality expressions, as

```
if (x == 0 || x == 7 || x == 14 || ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the if statement to the following:

```
if (x==0 || x==7 || x==14 || x==21 || x==-7 || x==-14)
{
  y=THURSDAY;
}
```

You cannot test a variable against multiple values at once.

In `C`, all non zero values evalute as true, for the purpose of boolean logic. As such, each number in your original `or` statement stands as its own condition. So `7` evaluates to true, and the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: this is not an answer, it should be a comment

Comment: @GameScripting: Of course it is. Not a perfect one, but it remains an answer

Comment: @GameScripting, have you ever heard of incremental answeres, via editing!?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 if (x==0||x==7||x==14||x==21||x==-7||x==-14)
    {
     y=THURSDAY;
    }
```

The way you wrote it, 7,14.. will be evaluated as true.

0 is false, rest are true.