# Syntactic sugar for if(x==10 || x==12), why not?

Tags: if-statement

I've recently seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082446/if-x-071421-7-14-y-thursday/14082462#14082462) question. Which contained (what I believe is) a very common early programer mistake of writing `if(x==10 || 12)` when you mean `if(x==10 || x==12)` which made me wonder. Why (to my knowledge) there is no support for this `if(x==10 || 12)` seemingly more natural syntax, or at least some similar syntax. So my questions are:

1) Is there some kind of syntactic sugar/macro expansion/shorthand for this kind of expression in any of the more common languages (c,c++,java,c#). If not, why not ?

2) Is there a way using java and eclipse to add this (as a compiler macro expansion or any other useable solution) ?

EDIT: clarification, I did not mean I wish to alter the meaning of `if(x==10 || 12)`. I was looking for syntactic sugar that is shorter than `if(x==10 || x==12)` but is functionally equivalent.

Comment: Python has an actual operator for something similar: `if x in (10, 12): ...`

Comment: In Javascript: `~[10,12].indexOf(x)`; The tilde is a shortcut for `!=-1`

Comment: PHP: `in_array($x, [10, 12])`

Comment: @JanDvorak Thou shalt not resist the php updatez.

Comment: `if (x == 10 || 12)` would basically be translated in `if ((x == 10) || (!!(12) == true))`. `(!!(x) == true)` applies to `x > 0`.

Comment: @Jack tell that to the hosting my manager has chosen

Comment: @TimvanElsloo Yes. In other words, `if (x==10 || 12)` already has a meaning in C++, albeit a different one. So the syntactic sugar that the OP asks for, would not _give_ this phrase a meaning, it would _alter_ its meaning!

Comment: I know the syntax I gave has a different meaning and I did not intend to alter it, I was asking if there exists a -similar- syntax that is shorter than if(x==10 || x==12) but does the same thing. a shorthand syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it's makes more sense for `if (x == 10 || 12)` to be interpreted exactly as it's written. That's "If x equals to 10, or 12 is truthy". If you want something done, write it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a switch case with butted up case statements in C#. You can't mess too much with ifs as you would break more legitimate cases and reduce readability. It would be syntactic salt rather than sugar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array or set lookup in languages that support compact representation of arrays or sets.

Javascript (as well as PHP and Java) has array literals:

```
if( [10,12].indexOf(x) != -1) ...
```

you can also use the bitwise negation as a shortcut for `!=-1`:

```
if(~[10,12].indexOf(x)) ...
```

Php 5.4 has array literals as well, and you can use them without a temp variable from 5.5 (I think). This should be superlinear as well, but generates notices unless you use `@` or `in_array`:

```
if(@[10=>true, 12=>true][$x]) ...
```

A regex lookup is also an option in languages that support compact regex syntax and you're matching strings. This has the benefit of being potentially faster than array search:

```
if(/^(10|12)$/.test(x)) ...
```

A switch has also been suggested:

```
switch(x){
  case 10:
  case 12:
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that was allowed, how would you write a condition like this one:

```
if( x == a || b )
```

where `x` and `a` are chars or integers and `b` can be either `true` or `false`?

For example:

```
x = 'a';
b = true;

// later in the program
if( x == 'c' || b )
```